# my php code shows as text

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm trying to create a search on a website I'm making for homework with a database called animal that is saved on an easy php server. However, when I run the search, the php code shows up as text. Can someone please help me with this?

```
    <?php
    $criteria = $_GET["criteria"];
    $Field = $_GET["animal"];
    $link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'criteria', 'animal');
    if (!$link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo 'Connected successfully';
    $result = array(connection -> query("SELECT * FROM animal WHERE $Field Like %criteria%"));
    mysql_close($link);
    echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: Your query is missing `FROM`.

Comment: You are also setting the $result = the query then echo $result right after. If you are planning on executing that query you need to call a method to do so first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: You also have a space in your opening php tag `<? php` should just be `<?php`.

Answer (score 2):

I see that you have a space between the `<?` and `php` in the opening php tag.

Remove the space to use php tags. It should be  `<?php`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $result = array(connection -> query("SELECT * animal WHERE $Field Like %criteria%"));
```

should be

```
    $result = array(connection -> query("SELECT * FROM animal WHERE $Field Like %$criteria%"));
```